# Why base64EncodeData doesn't work?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

```
NSString *result = [encData base64EncodeData:encData];
```

why base64EncodeData does't work??
 it had the message like:

> -[NSConcreteData base64EncodeData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e1f020

Answer (score 2):

There is no `base64EncodeData` method in the official SDK. If you are using third-party libraries/code that define categories on `NSData`/`NSString` for base64 encoding/decoding, be sure to add them to your project.

Comment: Also, consider filing an enhancement request for base64 encoding/encoding in the official SDK: http://bugreporter.apple.com