# how to use base64EncodeData?

Tags: iphone

```
NSString *result = [encData base64EncodeData:encData];
```

why base64EncodeData does't work? it had the message like:

> :-[NSConcreteData base64EncodeData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e1f020

how to use it? Someboby suggust me that to inlude the third library, how to import it?

Comment: Duplicate of (15 hours ago) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592794/why-base64encodedata-doest-work/ Do you know you can add comments to an answer, or edit a question?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the article in http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html and download the third party class there

Answer (score 1):

It's not in a standard library, you need to declare and implement additional category to make it work.

```
@interface NSString (Base64)
- (NSString *)base64EncodeData;
@end

@implementation NSString (Base64)
- (NSString *)base64EncodeData
{
    return .. do something with self to make a base64 encoded string ..;
}
@end
```